# Backbone Router root duplicates in the url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've just finished developing my first Backbone app and I detected a small quirk with the Router which I don't seem to be able to fix.

My routes look like this:

```
routes: {
  '': 'index',
  'jobs/:id': 'viewJob',
  '*default': 'notFound'
}
```

It works fine when serving the app from the server root, but it doesn't when I serve it from a subfolder. In that case I always get the default route.

I though adding the *root* param to the backbone history would do the trick so I added it like this:

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, root: '/subdir/' });
```

With this the app seems to load as expected but the Router is automatically adding the *root* to all the routes and it ends up being duplicated, so when I first visit the website:

```
http://mysite.com/subdir/
```

It loads the app and changes it to this:

```
http://mysite.com/subdir/subdir/
```

This makes the app to break when reloading the page or using the browser back button as that route doesn't really exist.

What would be the approach to avoid this? I don't want to hardcode the folder name in the routes as it might change or be served from the root.

**UPDATE:** I've just realized I was adding the duplicated folder name myself using router.navigate somewhere in my code. I just removed it and everything works as expected.

Comment: Could you share your exact code (with the callback)? I've just created a router in a subdir and it is working just fine.

Comment: Also what is the issue when "it doesn't when I serve it from a subfolder"?

Comment: The issue was in somewhere else in my code, I was calling router.navigate('/subdir/') and it was getting added to the url, making the subdir name duplicated.Removing that made the trick and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small guess.. do you really want pushState turned on? This can cause problems on reload if the server is not setup to serve out of the new directory.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it still duplicates the folder name, but it uses the hashtag instead.